# How to get geom_area() to not be stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I would like to have the two areas in my area plot to not be stacked.

At the minute I am subtracting the blue area from the red area to get the area you see here. Although, because the blue points are greater than the red points, the whole thing falls apart so I am also using max(value, 0) to prevent negative values.

[image: Chart]

How can I get it so that my area chart allows the blue to simply sit on top of the red, so that I can just have the red as a straight line along the top.

I can't just add a box because this is the percentage chart, but I need the same for the actual values as well.

```
ggplot(progress_targets_total, aes(x=wave, y=perc, fill=group)) + geom_area()
```

Here is my code. Very basic. I assume there is some aesthetic term I can just throw into the geom_area() part but the google is not helping today.

Cheers

Some data

```
    wave value      perc  group
1    1   893 95.101171 Actual
2    1    46  4.898829 Target
3    2   796 90.351873 Actual
4    2    85  9.648127 Target
5    3   694 85.679012 Actual
6    3   116 14.320988 Target

structure(list(wave = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), 
    value = c(893, 46, 796, 85, 694, 116, 858, 86, 812, 61, 643, 
    157, 746, 190, 416, 454, 10, 813, 0, 914, 0, 866, 0, 794), 
    perc = c(95.1011714589989, 4.89882854100107, 90.3518728717367, 
    9.64812712826334, 85.679012345679, 14.320987654321, 90.8898305084746, 
    9.11016949152542, 93.0126002290951, 6.98739977090493, 80.375, 
    19.625, 79.7008547008547, 20.2991452991453, 47.816091954023, 
    52.183908045977, 1.21506682867558, 98.7849331713244, 0, 100, 
    0, 100, 0, 100), group = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Target", "Actual"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `position = 'identity'` to unstack the areas:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(progress_targets_total, aes(x=wave, y=value, fill= group)) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4, position = 'identity')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I bet I've done that a hundred times before, but for some reason it slipped my mind and the internet didn't have the answer.

I'll leave it here in case someone else is like me sometime. Thanks

Comment: @LeonhardEuler please always leave good questions and answers and don't delete it. This is what Stack overflow is about - increasing the Q&A. It is almost certain that someone (maybe yourself!) will have the same problem in the future.